# How can I restrict content (images, etc) until the user is signed in using PHP?

Tags: php

Noobie question: I have sensitive content (images) that I want to place in a directory and show a user only AFTER they've logged in. What is the standard procedure for this without relying on simply randomly generated filenames and a .htaccess file that specifies no directory listing?  I'm working in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [protect users' file being accessed so only owner can access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642473/protect-users-file-being-accessed-so-only-owner-can-access)

Comment: That's perfect - of course after I post it I too found a few related questions like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248928/restrict-content-access-to-logged-in-users-with-php).  Thanks @Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put these images in a different folder outside of the public_html (so nobody can access them). Then via script, if a user is logged in, you get the image file content and then change the header. If a user is not logged, you can display a random image or showing a default image.

for example, the public html folder is: `/var/www`
your image folder can be: `/registered_user/images/`

Then in your PHP script you can write:

```
<?php
if(!userLogged() || !isset($_GET['image'])) {
  header('Location: /');
  die();
}
$path = '/registered_user/images/';
$file = clean($_GET['image']); // you can create a clean function that only get valid character for files

$filename = $path . $file;
if(!file_exists($filename)) {
  $filename = '/var/www/images/bogus.jpg';
}
$imageInfo = getimagesize($filename);

header ('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename));
header ('Content-type: ' . $imageInfo['mime']);
readfile ($filename);
```

Then when you call the image you can use: `<img src="/script.php?image=filename">`

Comment: That's almost exactly what I did:
`$filename = './images/' . $_GET['img'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

if ( is_file ( $filename ) ) {

 $img = file_get_contents( $filename );

echo $img;

}

exit();`
I'm going to put an "else" statement in there for a default image, but for now... I think that will work.  Thanks!

Comment: you welcome. I recommend to echo the file content right way so you don't have to create a variable (no extra memory).

Comment: Excellent idea.  I'll make that change now.  Thanks BookOfZeus!

Comment: You can also use: ``RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mysessioncookie=([^;]+)` and set the cookie in PHP