# Only allow logged in users access to all files in a directory

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have a directory with many files in it at the moment that is publicly available by browsing to it.

I'm trying to figure out how I can make this directory only available to users who are currently logged into my web application.

Is it possible to make the .htaccess file check a script/session variable before proceeding to a subdirectory?

Comment: See http://www.fromdev.com/2012/08/Best-Open-Source-Web-Based-File-Explorer-Applications.html may be used as file manager and integrated in your app.

Comment: Maybe what you can do is to store the user ip in the htaccess and redirect the user to the protected folder. If the user ip is not in the htaccess, you may redirect the user somewhere or throw an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248928/restrict-content-access-to-logged-in-users-with-php?rq=1 ?